# Filtering table rows with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table showing registered users and the rows of this table can be filtered according to Status (active/inactive users or both) or User Type (admin/user or both). In order to make sure all of the table rows are filtered according to both criteria, I have PHP generate a 'info' attribute for each table row. Info can be one of four things:

- Active Admin
- Active User
- Inactive Admin
- Inactive User

This made it easy to filter out the user rows according to the options selected in the two filter drop-downs.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to filter them when **Both** is selected for one of the filter drop-downs--I know there's a more efficient way to do this than running six if statements every time one of the drop-downs is changed.

Here's my code:

```
function toggleAll(){
    var selectedString = $('#userStatusDropDown').val() + ' ' + $('#userTypeDropDown').val();
    switch (selectedString){
        case 'Both Both':
            $('#tableUsers tr').show();
            break;

        default:
            $('#tableUsers tr:gt(1)').hide();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="'+selectedString+'"]').show();
    }
}


$(document).ready(function(){   
        toggleAll();

        // admin/user drop down changes
        $('#userTypeDropDown').change(function(){
            toggleAll();
        });

        // active/inactive drop down changed
        $('#userStatusDropDown').change(function(){
            toggleAll();
        });
});
```

Comment: If there are four groups, why not use `$('#tableUsers tr').show()` / `.hide()` instead, which will select all `tr`s. Also is there a reason for using both `table` and `#tableUsers`?

Comment: I used showAll() and hideAll() so that it targeted specific rows--I have a row at the beginning that contains my drop-down boxes and I don't want that to get hidden each time. There is no reason for both table and #tableUsers thanks for pointing that out--I will fix.

Comment: As a side note, if there is one header row, you can select all rows coming after that first row with `$('#tableUsers tr:gt(0)')`.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going with this, wasn't as sloppy as I thought:

```
function toggleAll(){
    var selectedString = $('#userStatusDropDown').val() + ' ' + $('#userTypeDropDown').val();
    switch (selectedString){
        case 'Both Both':
            $('#tableUsers tr').show();
            break;

        case 'Both Admin':
            $('#tableUsers tr:gt(1)').hide();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="Active Admin"]').show();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="Inactive Admin"]').show();
            break;

        case 'Both User':
            $('#tableUsers tr:gt(1)').hide();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="Active User"]').show();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="Inactive User"]').show();
            break;

        case 'Active Both':
            $('#tableUsers tr:gt(1)').hide();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="Active User"]').show();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="Active Admin"]').show();
            break;

        case 'Inactive Both':
            $('#tableUsers tr:gt(1)').hide();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="Inactive User"]').show();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="Inactive Admin"]').show();
            break;

        default:
            $('#tableUsers tr:gt(1)').hide();
            $('#tableUsers tr[info="'+selectedString+'"]').show();
    }
}
```